# ListView doen't work in fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment

My class is extended Fragment. It seems like my list can't be clicked.

// OnCLickListener For List Items

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText ( getActivity(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
            toast.show ( );
        }
    });
```

ps1. This code work well when I use Activity class.

ps2. i've already set android:focusable="false" but it doesn't work

ps3. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are you using custom listview? Inside which method is your above code? i.e inside oncreate or oncreateview?

Comment: yes,I used SimpleCursorAdapter.
this method is inside onCreateView

Comment: Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in your layout file of the custom listview

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in your layout file of the custom listview or in each of the views add `android:focusable="false"`. If any of the view in custom listview has focusable view then onitemclick does not work.